# Discover Wamp Server Absolute Path

Tags: php, include, wampserver

I have searched all over google and cannot find out how to discover the absolute path for a `php include`

my site is structured like

`wamp/www/MYSITE/resources/index-variables.php`

I am using wampserver 2.5 if that helps.

MAYBE I can create some file to display the absolute path?

such as, `wamp/www/MYSITE/resources/find-path.php`

thanks so much

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665064/project-links-do-not-work-on-wamp-server/23990618#23990618

Comment: If you use an absolute path, it wont work when you move the code to a real server

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes that link worked,  I ended up using "c:/wamp/www" instead of var/www/ I tried back slashes but with that link, it was more explanitory

Comment: Windows has no `var` folder by default. That is a unix folder name. When looking at tutorials about Apache/PHP/MySQL remember most are written with unix in mind. You will have to pick this up and reorganise the folders in your head before applying them to a Windows Environmant